# What is $\rho$ and $\sigma$ in this theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This might be a silly question but, heres a note I made in linear algebra class:

*Suppose we have $Ax = \lambda x$, then $\rho(A)x = \rho(\lambda)x $, so $\rho(\sigma(A)) \subset \sigma(\rho(A))$.*

My question is... What is $\rho$ and $\sigma$?? I'm quessing that $\sigma$ should be the spectrum of the matrix?

Comment: I think $\rho$ is spectral radius of matrix $A$

Comment: $\sigma$ is the spectrum of $A$, the set of eigenvalues.

Comment: IMHO $\rho$ is a polynomial. Then the statement makes *sense* and it is true as well :)

Comment: I think your teacher meant to write $p$, but you transcribed it as $\rho$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that $\rho$ rather wants to denote *any polynomial* $p$, and $\sigma$ means the *spectrum* of $A$, i.e. the set of its eigenvalues.

For, if $p(X)=X^n$, then $p(A)x=A^nx=\lambda^nx$, so this also holds for the linear combination of these, hence for any polynomial $p$, we have $p(A)x=p(\lambda)x$.

So that, if $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$, then $p(\lambda)\in\sigma(p(A))$.